# Can python controll applications like itunes?

Tags: python, controller, itunes

How can I tell python to skip a song in itunes or something like that. Is it possible? I use to have scripts with auto hot key(ahk) to copy certain songs and stuff but the way ahk worked was by taking control of your mouse so if you had an ahk script running you couldnt use your mouse. So can python interact with applications like itunes without using your mouse?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Python [supports OSA](http://docs.python.org/library/macosa.html), and so can interact with any application that supports AppleScript.

Answer (score 1):

In windows you can with win32com

see here
http://code.activestate.com/recipes/498241-scripting-itunes-for-windows-with-python/

Answer (score 1):

You can perform applescript translations using [appscript module](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/appscript/)

Here is a simple command that checks if iTunes is running and activates it

```
import appscript
iTunes = appscript.app('iTunes')
if iTunes.isrunning():
  iTunes.activate()
```

**Note : However, the website says that appscript project is no longer active**